# Using QuickOSM plugin on QGIS. I want to select all the points that would show food options(convenience stores, fast food, supermarkets, etc)

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I'm generating a map of Tennessee based on OSM data. How can I choose the features/layers a need for my task?

Comment: Just add a Key from the Key list. Refer to my earlier answer on your earlier questions.

Comment: If someone responds with the right answer, it is a good to mark the answers as accepted answer generally speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the relevant key

[image]

Or type "shop" in the preset text box:

[image]